# Не могу скопировать свой SSH-ключ

Tags: git, macos, zsh

Проблема с Git, не могу скопировать свой SSH-ключ.
Команда  clip < ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub  не работает.
Команда ~ cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub выдает zsh: permission denied.
У меня Мак. Помогите пожалуйста, целый день мучаюсь(

```
ls -la ~ | grep ssh
-rw-------@ 1 Mac staff 20 19 фев 21:10 .lesshst
drwx------@ 4 Mac staff 128 19 фев 21:28 .ssh
```

Comment: дополните вопрос выводом команд `id -a` и `ls -la ~ | grep ssh`

Comment: Добрый вечер, я должен ввести команду id -a, потом ls -la ~ | grep ssh, а потом ~ cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub?

Comment: это просто команды. выполните их друг за другом. `id` покажет пользователя под которым вы работаете, `ls` покажет листинг домашнего каталога отфильтровав по слову ssh - для того чтобы увидеть какие права выставлены на папку .ssh

Comment: s -la ~ | grep ssh
-rw-------@  1 Mac  staff     20 19 фев 21:10 .lesshst
drwx------@  4 Mac  staff    128 19 фев 21:28 .ssh.  А теперь как узнать SHH ключ?

Comment: а под каким вы пользователем? что показывает `ls -ls ~/.ssh`?